# Reordering separate nested divs for Mobile (CSS)

Tags: css, flexbox

I have to re-order nested divs for a mobile view and I am unsure how to accomplish this properly since they are not direct descendants. I don
t want to change the div layout because that would affect the regular view and I don't want to revamp the whole NavBar unless I really need to.

Here's the div layout:

```
<header class="header-top">
  <nav class="navbar-primary left">
    ...
    <span class="navbar-links">
      <div class="dropbar-content show">
        ...
      </div>
    </span>
  </nav>
  <div class="profile-component">
    <div class="profile show">
      <div class="greeting">.../div>
    </div>
    <div class="authorization-links">
      <a href="#" data-test="top-link-logout" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here's my order I want the mobile Nav dropdown to look like:

1. `header > div.profile-component > div.profile-show > div.greeting`
2. `header > nav > span.navbar-links > div.dropbar-content.show`
3. `header > div.profile-component > div.authorization-links`

To do this with flex I would need to make the header a flex container, but none of these items would be flex items since they are not direct descendants... Or is there a way?

Comment: Do you use some sort of framework? they usually provide this functionality

Comment: I tried and googled too much to post. Ended up just putting a conditional div for mobile view in the place I needed it with the greeting, and left the old one for the regular view...